# Type annotation in "value" parameter in hibernate 6

Tags: spring-3, hibernate-6.x

I am migrating to spring 3 and part of that moving to hibernate 6.X. Have some old code for hibernate I am wondering how I can use

```
@Type(
         type = "json",
        parameters = {
          @Parameter(
              name = "type",
              value =
   "com.mypackage.Summary")
        })
```

in hibernate 6, it has a field "value"  `Class<? extends UserType<?>> value()`

Please help